# Nested preferences.xml

Tags: android, include, nested, preferences, android-preferences

Is it somehow possible to include one `preferences.xml` into another, like it can be done for layouts with the `<include />` tag?

Let's say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceScreen 
        android:title="@string/pref_group_title_visual">
        <include 
            preferences_filename="xml/pref_visual"/>
    </PreferenceScreen>
...
```

Answer (score 27):

Solution here it is to inflate both preference files from PreferencesActivity. For example:

```
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.additional_options);
```

Comment: This does, in fact, work.  Perfectly.  I added a little code snippet below that adds the ability for developers to display preferences that would only be available to the unsigned app pushed to the phone/emulator :)

Answer (score 17):

The solution soul shows works.  It can be expanded to only show preferences if you're the developer using an unsigned version of the app ;)

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.options);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.additional_options);
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.developer_options);
}
```

I created a blog post regarding this issue and have a complete working code example available for download.
http://androidfu.blogspot.com/2012/05/developer-debug-with-nested-preferences.html

Answer (score 4):

To truly achieve the nesting effect you can use this technique to relocate the loaded preferences to a group already loaded.

```
PreferenceCategory notifications = (PreferenceCategory) getPreferenceScreen ().findPreference (PreferenceKey.pref_notifications.name ());
addPreferencesFromResource (R.xml.pref_notifications, notifications);
```

Where the enhanced addPreferencesFromResource is defined as:

```
private void addPreferencesFromResource (int id, PreferenceGroup newParent) {
    PreferenceScreen screen = getPreferenceScreen ();
    int last = screen.getPreferenceCount ();
    addPreferencesFromResource (id);
    while (screen.getPreferenceCount () > last) {
        Preference p = screen.getPreference (last);
        screen.removePreference (p); // decreases the preference count
        newParent.addPreference (p);
    }
}
```

It works for any PreferenceGroup such as PreferenceScreen and PreferenceCategory.

Answer (score 2):

No, it seems to be impossible. But there's a simple workaround. You can make another `PreferenceActivity` that loads nested `PreferenceScreen`. And in the main preference.xml file you need to create a `Preference` object and set an `Intent` object for it in code (using `setIntent()` method). This `Intent` must be used to create the second `PreferenceActivity`.