# How to create preference headers groups in Android PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, preferences

I am using preference headers to create settings activity using `PreferenceActivity`. I am trying to divide the headers into categories/groups, like this one (there are categories Wireless & Networks, Device, Personal, ...):

[image]

Anyway, even that Android Developers site is about this way of creating preference activity, I couldn't find any way how to create the same preferences activity like they have on the image. The only I managed to do is simple list of preference headers.

The only thing I have found is [this](http://xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article4/master-on-off-preferences-with-ice-cream-sandwich), but that works kinda... strange. So that does not seem as an option.

**So my question is: How to create `PreferenceActivity` using preference headers with possibility of dividing headers into categories and with possibility of using master on/off switches?**

Some of my code:

**preference_headers.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header 
        android:fragment="cz.vse.myevents.activity.SettingsActivity$EventsFragment"
        android:title="@string/settings_events"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda" />
    <header 
        android:fragment="cz.vse.myevents.activity.SettingsActivity$OrganizationsFragment"
        android:title="@string/settings_subscribed_organizations"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"  />
</preference-headers>
```

**SettingsActivity**:

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    super.onBuildHeaders(target);
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);
}
```

I am not posting fragments resources, think it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the best solution is creation of three different blocks of code - one for pre-Honeycomb, one for post-Honeycomb and one for tablets.

Usage of preference headers is effective on tablets only, so they remain on tablets only. No grouping is used here.

Preference headers on post-Honeycomb are kinda useless, so the best is usage of typical `PreferenceScreen` in a `PreferenceFragment`. Groups can be made easily by `PreferenceCategory`.

And finally, for the pre-Honeycomb, the deprecated way without using `PrefrenceFragment` is the only way.

Sadly there is a lot of code duplication, but the `UnifiedPreference` library mentioned in the answer by Leandros is buggy - it ignores `PreferenceFragment` totally so it is useless (at least for me).

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20806812/1139784 about reducing some of the code duplication.

Answer (score 10):

This is preference category example, you can use preference category and set respective fragment and achieve this, let me know if I misunderstood your case.

Here is sample layout

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Heading1">
        <Preference 
            android:title="title1"
            android:summary="summary1"
            android:key="keyName"/>

       <Preference 
            android:title="title2"
            android:summary="summary2"
            android:key="keyName"/>
</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Heading2">
        <Preference 
            android:title="title3"
            android:summary="summary3"
            android:key="keyName"/>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: This creates titles inside the fragment (property pane). The question is about creating titles in the headers secion (created by the `loadHeadersFromResource`).

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the answer from [T. Folsom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2066060/t-folsom), here is my implementation:

res/layout/preference_header_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/header_icon_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

res/values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>

    <dimen name="header_icon_width">28dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

in your PreferenceActivity class:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        /*
         *  the headers must be restored before the super call in order
         *  to be ready for the call to setListAdapter() 
         */
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("headers")) {
            setHeaders((ArrayList<Header>)savedInstanceState.getSerializable("headers"));
        }
    }

    // as suggest by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551673/android-headers-categories-in-preferenceactivity-with-preferencefragment
    if(onIsMultiPane()) getIntent().putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, PreferencesFragment.class.getName());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551673/android-headers-categories-in-preferenceactivity-with-preferencefragment
    // Select the displayed fragment in the headers (when using a tablet) :
    // This should be done by Android, it is a bug fix
    if(getHeaders() != null) {

        final String displayedFragment = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT);
        if (displayedFragment != null) {
            for (final Header header : getHeaders()) {
                if (displayedFragment.equals(header.fragment)) {
                    switchToHeader(header);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}

/**
 * Populate the activity with the top-level headers.
 */
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
    // we have to save the headers as the API call getHeaders() is hidden.
    setHeaders(target);
    loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.settings_headers, target);
}

private List<Header> headers;

private void setHeaders(List<Header> headers) {
    this.headers = headers;
}

private List<Header> getHeaders() {
    return headers;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putSerializable("headers", (ArrayList<PreferenceActivity.Header>)headers);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    if (adapter == null) {
        super.setListAdapter(null);
    } else {
        super.setListAdapter(new HeaderAdapter(this, getHeaders()));
    }
}

private static class HeaderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Header> {
    static final int HEADER_TYPE_CATEGORY = 0;
    static final int HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL = 1;
    private static final int HEADER_TYPE_COUNT = HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL + 1;

    private static class HeaderViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        TextView summary;
    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    static int getHeaderType(Header header) {
        if (header.fragment == null && header.intent == null) {
            return HEADER_TYPE_CATEGORY;
        } else {
            return HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Header header = getItem(position);
        return getHeaderType(header);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false; // because of categories
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return getItemViewType(position) != HEADER_TYPE_CATEGORY;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return HEADER_TYPE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    public HeaderAdapter(Context context, List<Header> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        HeaderViewHolder holder;
        Header header = getItem(position);
        int headerType = getHeaderType(header);
        View view = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new HeaderViewHolder();
            switch (headerType) {
            case HEADER_TYPE_CATEGORY:
                view = new TextView(getContext(), null,
                        android.R.attr.listSeparatorTextViewStyle);
                holder.title = (TextView) view;
                break;

            case HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL:
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_header_item,
                        parent, false);
                holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                holder.title = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
                holder.summary = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
                break;
            }
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (HeaderViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        // All view fields must be updated every time, because the view may
        // be recycled
        switch (headerType) {
        case HEADER_TYPE_CATEGORY:
            holder.title.setText(header.getTitle(getContext()
                    .getResources()));
            break;
        case HEADER_TYPE_NORMAL:
            holder.icon.setImageResource(header.iconRes);
            holder.title.setText(header.getTitle(getContext()
                    .getResources()));
            CharSequence summary = header.getSummary(getContext()
                    .getResources());
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(summary)) {
                holder.summary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.summary.setText(summary);
            } else {
                holder.summary.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

With all this code in place, creating headers is simply:

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <header android:title="atitle" />
</preference-headers>
```

Hope this helps someone. I know it took me some time to get working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty straightforward. From what I found, the root `PreferenceActivity` itself doesn't support adding category/section titles to it, it seems you can only add `Header`s -- which isn't very interesting.

So what you first need to do is not do any heavy lifting in your `PreferenceActivity` itself and go straight into loading a `PreferenceFragment`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle("Settings");

    // Display the fragment as the main content.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, new PreferencesFragment())
            .commit();

}

public static class PreferencesFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
```

Once you've done this you can now do all the work in your `PreferenceFragment`, and the great news is that **you can now use categories**!

Your R.xml.prefs file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:summary="Login credentials"
        android:title="Login credentials" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="username"
            android:summary="Username"
            android:title="Username" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="password"
            android:summary="Password"
            android:title="Password" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:summary="Settings"
        android:title="Settings" >
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="persist"
            android:summary="Yes/No"
            android:title="Keep me signed in" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Just create a `PreferenceCategory` for each new category you wish to add.

Answer (score -2):

AOSP settings_headers.xml implementation:

```
<preference-headers
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!-- WIRELESS and NETWORKS -->
    <header android:title="@string/header_category_wireless_networks" />

    <!-- Wifi -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/wifi_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings"
        android:title="@string/wifi_settings_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_wireless" />

    <!-- Bluetooth -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/bluetooth_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings"
        android:title="@string/bluetooth_settings_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth2" />

    <!-- Data Usage -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/data_usage_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DataUsageSummary"
        android:title="@string/data_usage_summary_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_data_usage" />

    <!-- Operator hook -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"
        android:id="@+id/operator_settings">
        <intent android:action="com.android.settings.OPERATOR_APPLICATION_SETTING" />
    </header>

    <!-- Other wireless and network controls -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/wireless_settings"
        android:title="@string/radio_controls_title"
        android:breadCrumbTitle="@string/wireless_networks_settings_title"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/empty_icon" />

   <!-- Ethernet -->
   <header
        android:id="@+id/ethernet_settings"
        android:title="@string/eth_radio_ctrl_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_ethernet"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.ethernet.EthernetSettings"/>

    <!-- DEVICE -->
    <header android:title="@string/header_category_device" />

    <!-- Sound -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/sound_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_sound"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.SoundSettings"
        android:title="@string/sound_settings" />

    <!-- Display -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/display_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_display"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DisplaySettings"
        android:title="@string/display_settings" />

    <!-- Storage -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/storage_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.deviceinfo.Memory"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_storage"
        android:title="@string/storage_settings" />

    <!-- Battery -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/battery_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_battery"
        android:title="@string/power_usage_summary_title" />

    <!-- Application Settings -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.applications.ManageApplications"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_applications"
        android:title="@string/applications_settings"
        android:id="@+id/application_settings" />

    <!-- TEMPORARY FACTORY STARTER WILL BE REMOVED WITH UPDATED SETTINGS -->
    <header
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_applications"
        android:title="Factory"
        android:id="@+id/application_settings" >
        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.MAIN"
                android:targetPackage="com.jamdeo.tv.sample.factory"
                android:targetClass="com.jamdeo.tv.sample.factory.TvFactoryMainActivity" />
    </header>

    <!-- Manufacturer hook -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.WirelessSettings"
        android:id="@+id/manufacturer_settings">
        <intent android:action="com.android.settings.MANUFACTURER_APPLICATION_SETTING" />
    </header>


    <!-- PERSONAL -->
    <header android:title="@string/header_category_personal" />

    <!-- Data Sync. The settings activity will ensure this is resolved to an
         activity on the system image, otherwise it will remove this
         preference. -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.accounts.ManageAccountsSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_sync"
        android:title="@string/sync_settings"
        android:id="@+id/sync_settings" />

    <!-- Location -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.LocationSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_location"
        android:title="@string/location_settings_title"
        android:id="@+id/location_settings" />

    <!-- Security -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.SecuritySettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_security"
        android:title="@string/security_settings_title"
        android:id="@+id/security_settings" />

    <!-- Language -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/language_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.inputmethod.InputMethodAndLanguageSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_language"
        android:title="@string/language_settings" />

    <!-- Backup and reset -->
    <header
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.PrivacySettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_backup"
        android:title="@string/privacy_settings"
        android:id="@+id/privacy_settings" />


    <!-- SYSTEM -->
    <header android:title="@string/header_category_system" />

    <!-- Dock -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/dock_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DockSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_dock"
        android:title="@string/dock_settings" />

    <!-- Date & Time -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/date_time_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DateTimeSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_date_time"
        android:title="@string/date_and_time_settings_title" />

    <!-- Accessibility feedback -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/accessibility_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_accessibility"
        android:title="@string/accessibility_settings" />

    <!-- Development -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/development_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_development"
        android:title="@string/development_settings_title" />

    <!-- About Device -->
    <header
        android:id="@+id/about_settings"
        android:fragment="com.android.settings.DeviceInfoSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_about"
        android:title="@string/about_settings" />

</preference-headers>
```

Just use `<header>` only with `android:title` attribute.

Comment: This does not work - just another header that does nothing is created and does not show any group division. I think that in your example there are some programmatical stuff missing.

Comment: I looked into the source code of the settings activity there is much you need to do for getting the same result. I ended in proxying the Adapter of the settings and I returned a different view for my headlines.

Comment: As mentioned by @James it doesn't work. Do not waste your time.

Comment: I think the best solution is not using headers. Only for tablets.