# Dynamically load a preference depending on SDK version

Tags: android, android-layout, preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity in my android app which I use to show the settings screen. I would like to have a "MultiSelectListPreference" in it, but I ran into a problem that it doesn't work on pre-API11 versions of android, because it got introduced in API11. 
No problem, there, I worked around it by having two xml layouts, one with "MultiSelectListPreference" residing in res/xml-v11 and another one with just "Preference" residing in res/xml, which I handle with a custom dialog.

The xml file in res/xml-v11 looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Preference android:key="time"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:title="@string/time" />
<MultiSelectListPreference android:key="days_multi"
                           android:persistent="false"
                           android:title="@string/days" />
<ListPreference android:key="action"
                android:persistent="false"
                android:title="@string/action" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

And the one in res/xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Preference android:key="time"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:title="@string/time" />
<Preference android:key="days_dialog"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:title="@string/days" />
<ListPreference android:key="action"
                android:persistent="false"
                android:title="@string/action" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

As you can see, the only differense is the second element in the list, the rest is exactly the same. Is there a better way to handle this to reuse the same code in one file and reference the remaining piece dynamically, depending on Android version? And Ideal solution would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Preference android:key="time"
            android:persistent="false"
            android:title="@string/time" />
<Preference source="days.xml" />
<ListPreference android:key="action"
                android:persistent="false"
                android:title="@string/action" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

While I would also have files called days.xml under res/xml-v11 and res/xml containing the piece that is different.

I couldn't find anything related in the documentation and after searching here on StackOverflow. Does android offer a way to do this? Or perhaps there is some other way to factor out common code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes to mind is to use something like the `<include/>` tag. It seems that you cannot use it in preference xmls, but you can create your preferences in parts. So you would need to create prefs in your `PreferencesActivity` like this (where `R.xml.prefs_days` is your version specific file with 2 versions):

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_time);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_days);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs_action);
```

[Nested preferences.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314582/nested-preferences-xml)

Comment: That is exactly the approach I thought of right after publishing this question :) And it does work for me. But I can see sevaral drawbacks here, i.e. how would you wrap several preferences into a PreferenceCategory if they are spread over multiple files?

Comment: Good question, that is out of my realm of knowledge when it comes to preferences, as I have not used them in a more advanced way like this.