# Android preference subscreen

Tags: android, toolbar, android-preferences

I'm using `PreferenceFragment` to inflate preferences from a xml. In my xml, I have a preference subscreen. When I click on this preference, a new preference screen is showed. To do that, as google documentation says, I have declared another preference screen in my xml file like this:

```
 <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_info_section">

    <PreferenceScreen
        android:key="LegalPref"
        android:title="@string/legal"
        android:persistent="false">

        <Preference
            android:key="PolicyPref"
            android:title="@string/policy">               
        </Preference>

        <Preference
            android:key="OpenSourcePref"
            android:title="@string/open_source">                
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceCategory>
```

The problem is that when I click on this preference item and the new screen is shown, my toolbar disappears, and only the secondary preference options are showed. The activity containing this preference fragment uses `Theme.AppCompat.Light` witch shows a toolbar at first, but when I click in the preference subscreen (which automatically shows the other preference options without create a new activity), the toolbar disappear.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357292/keep-the-actionbar-displayed-in-when-changing-preferencescreen

Comment: I think this is a very ugly workaround. I thought I was doing something wrong, but it seems than is the normal behaviour...

Comment: I raised a defect, please vote for it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207718

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a Preference subscreen, do the following:

1. Design the Fragment you want as the subscreen, in much the same construct as your main fragment.

```
public  class SubFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    ...
}
```

2. In your Preference that you click on to open a subscreen, write the attribute:

```
<Preference
    android:key="to_click_on"
    app:fragment="com.packagename.SubFragment"
    ...
    />
```

This alone should work without hiding the Toolbar of your Settings Activity.
The same is written in the Google documentation.
[image: Splitting into subscreens]
[Link to the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings)