# Android Alternative to PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I'm developing an app that is currently entirely composed of `Preferences`. I'm trying to add a refresh button to the ActionBar on a subscreen, and the solution proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21440685/show-up-button-in-actionbar-in-subscreen-preferences) is too hacky for a newbie like me. I require my application to interact with code a lot, e.g. dynamically grabbing a list of things and making them options inside a `CheckboxPreference`. It seems like the whole Preferences thing is meant to be used with static applications. I elected to use Preferences mostly to get the UI to look consistent.

What is my best bet given that I am on a tight deadline and need to be able to do things without requiring complicated hacks like the previous link? Would writing the Preferences stuff in Java instead of XML help? Are there ways of separating out nested `PreferenceScreen`s so that I can write code similar to if I had multiple `Activities`? Would trying to get the UI to look like Preferences but just be normal Activities be easier?

Answer (score 0):

You may find this library very helpful:
https://github.com/UdiOshi85/GenericSettings

Looks the same as the PreferenceScreen but with your own implementation.